Different answer for numerical integral from nquad and Mathematica
I am trying to write a function that returns the numerical answer of a very complicated integral. I have the following code
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import sympy as smp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.integrate import nquad
import cmath
from scipy.special import gamma #need the gamma function from scipy
#loading Gegenbauer from scipy.special
from scipy.special import eval_gegenbauer as G #gegenbauer

options={'limit':1000, 'epsabs':1e-12, 'epsrel':1e-12}

def IntZ(z,sp,s,l,lp):
    return (1-z**2)**((d-4)/2)/2*G(l,(d-3)/2,z)*G(lp,(d-3)/2,cmath.sqrt(-(3*s*(-1+z**2)+sp*(3+z**2))/((s*(-1+z**2)-sp*(3+z**2)))))
def ker(z,sp,s):
#     return -2+s/(sp-s)+(4*sp*(s+2*sp))/((s+2*sp)**2-s**2*z**2)
    return s*(1/(complex(0,-10**(-20))-s+sp)+(-1+z)/(s+2*sp-s*z)-(1+z)/(s+2*sp+s*z))

#These are all the prefactors of the integrand.

def prefactor(sp,s,sigma,l,lp):
    return ((gamma(l+1)*gamma((d-3)/2)*2**(2*d-3)*(np.pi)**((d-3)/2)*gamma((d-3)/2)*(2*lp+d-3))/(2**(d+1)*(np.pi)**((d-1)/2)*gamma(l+d-3)))*(((s-mu)**((d-3)/2)*2*cmath.sqrt((sp-1)*sigma)*cmath.sqrt(sp)*(sp-1)**(2*lp+1/2))/(cmath.sqrt(s)*(1-sp-sigma)*(sp-mu)**((d-3)/2)*(sp)**(2*lp+1/2)))

#this is the final integrand (sp and z) with all the factors coded in.
def integrand(z,sp,s,sigma,l,lp):
    return IntZ(z,sp,s,l,lp)*ker(z,sp,s)*prefactor(sp,s,sigma,l,lp)

def prefactor2(sp,s,sigma,lp):
    return ((s-mu)**((d-3)/2)*2*cmath.sqrt((sp-1)*sigma)*cmath.sqrt(sp)*(sp-1)**(2*lp+1/2))/(cmath.sqrt(s)*(1-sp-sigma)*(sp-mu)**((d-3)/2)*(sp)**(2*lp+1/2))

def fell(s,sigma,l,lp):
    return nquad(integrand,[[-1,1],[1,np.inf]],args=(s,sigma,lp,l),opts=[options,options])

Note that this only gives me the real part of the integral, which is fine. I also have the integraion defined in Mathematica with the following function:
d = 5; 
\[Mu] = 0; 
(*Here the z-integral is done numerically*)
Integral2[s_, \[Sigma]_, l_, lp_, MaxRes_, WorkPres_] := 
 NIntegrate[(l! Gamma[(d - 3)/2])/(
   2^(d + 1) \[Pi]^((d - 1)/2) Gamma[l + d - 3]) (s - \[Mu])^((d - 3)/
    2)/s^(1/2) 2^(2 d - 3) \[Pi]^((d - 3)/2) Gamma[(d - 3)/2] sp^(
   1/2)/(sp - \[Mu])^((d - 3)/2) (2 lp + d - 3) ((sp - 1)/sp)^(
   2 lp + 1/2) (2 Sqrt[(sp - 1) \[Sigma]])/(
   1 - sp - \[Sigma]) (s/(sp - (s + I 10^-20)) + t/(sp - t) + u/(
       sp - u) /. {u -> -s - t} /. {t -> (s (z - 1))/2}) (1 - z^2)^((
   d - 4)/2)/
   2 GegenbauerC[l, (d - 3)/2, 
    z] (GegenbauerC[lp, (d - 3)/2, Sqrt[
        1 + (4 a)/(-a + sp)]] /. {a -> (s t u)/(
         s t + t u + u s)} /. {u -> -s - t} /. {t -> (s (z - 1))/
       2}), {z, -1, 1}, {sp, 1, Infinity}, MaxRecursion -> MaxRes, 
  WorkingPrecision -> WorkPres, Method -> "GlobalAdaptive"]

When I run the code fell(200,45,4,4), I get the answer (915.9500431066836, 0.0008916854858398438). This looks reasonable enough since the error is very small. However, when I run the same integral in Mathematica, with the same values and MaxRecursion and WorkingPrecision set to 100 each, I get (Mathematica returns both the real and the imaginary part)
946.243126048692722003932251899650713550717875143021622444266774813501\
3068351836006101088945258421851 - 
 288.75854540972949504131273023372598463063894553182017391668357286673\
70457344996286394039275246094406 I

The reason for doing this integral using Python instead of Mathematica was because in Python it's much faster. Since both the answers are different, I am not sure which one I should believe in.
For the integral in Python, I have tried to change values of limit, epsabs and epsrel but it does not help a lot in changing the answer. The discrepancy becomes worse for larger values of the first two arguments of the function, where I get for fell(1800,1800,4,4) the answer (5582.867565858222, 90.11617121750788) but Mathematica returns
6600.16959988860178799109412672538944693500880870136958557262039403043\
5553207340978200772084077156640 - 
 5628.2185973484253452277428879848996442046986842344701373348873276687\
65333223655602231358008282651070 I

What is going wrong?

Great question. I don't have an answer for you but the first thing that comes to mind is that since the Gegenbauer polynomials are oscillatory, you might try to apply a method especially for oscillatory functions; it seems likely there is already such a function (perhaps dispatched via some option) in scipy. If you can, try reducing the order of the Gegenbauer polynomials to make the problem easier and see if the results agree better then. Good luck and have fun.

Look at the output from d=5;\[Mu]=0;s=200;\[Sigma]=45;l=4;lp=4; Apart[Simplify[...YourIntegrandWithSubsFora,u,t...,-1<=z<=1&&1<=sp<Infinity]]//InputForm and look at the size of the numbers you have and the number of different terms you have and you want to do a 2d numerical integration out to infinity and you want the result to be precisely accurate?!?!?  Wow. Is there any chance you could break that into a bunch of separate integrals and do a symbolic integral on some or all of them? Is there any chance you could determine why you can't do a symbolic integral on them and get exact answer?

Looks like zero denominators very near s==200 and those are going to make numeric integration harder and accuracy much harder. It might be the case that your integrand is symmetric about z==0. If that is true then you might be able to cut your time in half and possibly increase accuracy. It looks like your complex values may sum to about 10^-21 in large areas of your integrand and that makes me wonder why. Is that just floating point noise? Can the complex be removed to make this easier and more accurate? Test all this very carefully before you even think of trusting any of this.

d=5;\[Mu]=0;s=200;\[Sigma]=45;l=4;lp=4; Table[Plot[...YourIntegrandWithSubsFora,u,t...,{sp,190,210}],{z,-1,1,1/4}]
